# Full path for root url - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have root defined to point to "pages#home"

In the url it just shows "/". That's fine for most purposes. But for analytics reasons I need to have "/pages/home"

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you map the root in the routes file, it maps that action to the '/' url. This should do what you want:

**Edit, try this**

```
match "/" => redirect("/pages/home")
```

Unfortunately, you cannot use a path method there.

**Other solution**

In your pages controller:

```
def root
  redirect_to home_pages_url
end
```

In your routes file:

```
root :to => "pages#root"
```

Just basically creating a simple redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a link like this `<%= link_to 'Page home', home_pages_path %>`

Answer (score 0):

In `routes.rb` puts this at the end:

```
root to: redirect('/pages/home')
```